# Comparing Datatables in powershell

Tags: powershell, datatable

I Need your guidance.

How Can I compare two datatable and pass the unmatch value to another datatable in powershell?

For Example:

Datatable 1 (New Data)

```
  id   column
  1     a@a.com
  2     b@b.com
  3     c@a.com
  4     d@a.com
```

Datatable 2 (existing Data)

```
  id   column
  1     a@a.com
  2     b@b.com
  3     d@a.com
```

gonna pass not existing value to a New Datatable

Datatable 3 (not existing value on existing Data)

```
  id   column
  1     c@a.com
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try `$Datatable1 | Where-Object Column -notin $Datatable2.Column`